# What does "three-stone weakling" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjective-phrases

> Three-stone weakling

From Wikipedia, stone is defined as a unit：

> The stone or stone weight (abbreviation: st.) is an English and
>   imperial unit of weight or mass now equal to 14 avoirdupois pounds
>   (6.35029318 kg).

One stone is 14 pounds; Three stone would be 42 pounds.

A weakling is a person or animal that is physically weak and frail.

What does "three-stone weakling" mean? A weak person whose weights 42 pounds?

There is another phrase about three-stone: three-stone ring. Does "three-stone"  in this phrase mean 42 pounds too? It is quite heavy!

Comment: Probably "a person whose weight is 42 pounds". This is quite a small weight, so understandably, such person is weaker than the majority of persons.

Comment: 42 pounds is too heavy for a person?

Comment: A three stone ring is a ring (typically worn on a finger) that has three prominent gems.

Comment: Any person who weighs only 3 stones is either a *child* or dying of starvation.

Comment: This is the context and the source: https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term 'three-stone ring' may sound similar to 'three-stone weakling' but they are different.

A 'three stone ring' refers to the number of gems within the ring. Example: A wedding ring that has three diamonds.

The term "three stone weakling" refers to a person who is weak and underweight. 42 pounds is heavy, but not in human weight.

This is from 2005:
[image]

Asia has the lowest Average body mass(kg) being 57.7 which is 127.2067 pounds. That is more that 3 times more than 42 pounds.

[Link to where screenshot was taken from](http://bmcpublichealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2458-12-439#sec3)

Comment: Wedding rings are traditionally plain with no precious stones; a simple plain ring (band) in gold. You're thinking of an *engagement* ring.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it means LITERALLY that "someone weighs 3 stone".  It seems to me that it's more a figure of speech...If someone told you they had butterflies in their stomach, would you ask them why they are eating butterflies?

Comment: Butterflies in your stomach is an idiom, and a very common one, too. On the other hand,  "three-stone weakling" is not an idiom or a common expression,  a weakling will usually refer to a male person, most likely an adult, but name calling someone as a  3-stone weakling is hyperbolic.